# Getting and updating the latest related model in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

I've been following [this article](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/) and set myself up with these models:

```
class Topic extends Node{
    public function section(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Section')->latest();
    }
    public function allSections(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Section');
    }
}
class Section extends Model
{
    public function topic(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic');
    }
}
```

When I query the data using eager loading, the result is as expected, which is that for each **Topic**, only one **Section** is returned (the latest).

```
Topic::with('section')
   ->where('id', $id)
   ->get(); //returns one section for each topic
```

However, when I query like this:

```
$section = $topic->section()->get(); //returns many
```

it returns all the **Sections**. Similarly, when I try to `update`, it updates all the sections:

```
$topic->section()->update([
   'content'   => $input['section']
]); // updates many
```

How do I get it to `update` only the latest/intended one?

Comment: Because you are using the method for querying not the relationship pointer. It should be $topic->section->name or desired section attribute. Same for update $topic->section->save(['foo'=>'bar'])

Comment: The solution described in the article has some pitfalls. You've found one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it wrong. Try this:

```
$topic->section->update([
   'content'   => $input['section']
]);
```

Comment: You didn't provide any explanation on how to solve the problem.

Comment: This is not a problem. He used relation 'hasOne' like 'belongsToMany'.

Comment: Wrong. You should have explained that he was using the relationship query method instead of using the related object pointer, and then you put the code solution. It is a problem for him since he doesn't understand the concept.  This will improve your future answers.

Comment: Ok. I will. Thanks.